# when we try to call document object methods with direct refrence ex: var kk = document.getElementById; kk("someid") gives error?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var kk = document.getElementById;
kk("some_id");  // gives Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in chrome
```

but if we do that same with user defined object it works.

```
var obj = {
    some_function : function(a){
        alert(a);
    }
};
var kk = obj.some_function;
kk("hello");  // works
```

what is the reason for this error. i just checked in google chrome and it is not working, i came across this when i was creating a short version for `document.getElementById`, by var `$id = document.getElementById;` but it did not work. and one interesting thing is that here `$id === document.getElementById;` (true) and `typeof $id` is function.

is that because of some security reasons or something ?
sorry for weak english and i m not even good at making good title for questions.
thanks for answers.

Comment: Note that while `kk = obj.some_function` works in this case, it may not behave as intended in all cases, eg if `some_function` was making use of the `this` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). It will bind context to document.

```
var kk = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```